# How to make background color of link take up exact height of container div?

Tags: css, height, padding, background-color, highlight

Here's the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cnf6cjm2/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="header"><ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="selected-nav">Another Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul></div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
body {
    margin:10px;
    padding:0;
}

#header {
    height:92px;
    background:#58585a;
    position:relative;
}

#header ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:35px;
    right:16px;
}

#header ul li {
    display:inline;
    font-size:1.25em;
}

#header ul li a {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:1.5em;
    padding:35px 0;
}

#selected-nav {
    background:#ffa31a;
}
```

I have a header div that has a horizontal ul in it for a navigation. I have the ul absolutely positioned so that it is on the right side of the header div and vertically centered. What I want to do is highlight the current page in the navigation. I want the highlight to be a background color on the link and I want the link bg to fill up exactly the whole height.

The best thing I have come up with, see above jsfiddle, is to try and set just the correct padding on the link so that when you change the background color it will take up the desired height. It works on Chrome but it's off by one pixel on the top and bottom in FF and it's off by one pixel on the bottom in IE. Here's a screen shot of those:

[image]

I also tried setting the padding to go over quite a bit and then hide the overflow-y, but that did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this solution

http://jsfiddle.net/keLsc2op/

CSS

```
body {
    margin:10px;
    padding:0;
}

#header {
    height:92px;
    background:#58585a;
    position:relative;
}

#header ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    height:100%;
    line-height:86px;
    right:16px;
}

#header ul li {
    display:inline;
    font-size:1.25em;
}

#header ul li a {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:1.5em;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

#selected-nav {
    background:#ffa31a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
#header {
  height: 92px;
  background: #58585a;
  float: left;
}
#header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}
#header ul li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.25em;

  
}
#header ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  line-height:4.6;
}
#selected-nav {
  background: #ffa31a;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="selected-nav"><a href="#">Another Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```